# async await doesn't response in express.js with mysql.js

Tags: javascript, express, async-await, mysqljs

First I'm trying to **insert data into the restaurant table**.

After it finished (console log). It should call the second query (Insert audit). But it doesn't call that query and holds on the first function.

How do I fix this?

```js
async function createRestaurant(req, res, next) {
    const restaurant = {
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description
    }

    const audits = {
        description: req.body.description
    }



    let query = "INSERT INTO restaurant SET ?";
    await connection.query(query, restaurant, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error at res")
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("200 res")
            return true;

        }
    });

    let query2 = "INSERT INTO audits SET ?";
    await connection.query(query2, audits, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error at audit")

        } else {
            console.log("200 res")

        }
    });
}

module.exports = {
    createRestaurant: createRestaurant
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use async /  await in every where. If you want use async / await it should be a promise. Since mysqljs is not a promised based library you can't use async / await here.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use callback with async/await, the purpose of async/await is to write asynchronous code in a synchronous way. 
Indeed you can return an await call and use try/catch blocks.

In your example the function is returned in the first query callback, so the 2nd query is never reached.

```
async function createRestaurant(req, res, next) {
    const restaurant = {
      name: req.body.name,
      description: req.body.description
    }

    const audits = {
      description: req.body.description
    }

    try {
      let query = "INSERT INTO restaurant SET ?";
      let resRestaurant = await connection.query(query, restaurant);
      console.log(200, 'resRestaurant');

      let query2 = "INSERT INTO audits SET ?";
      let resAudit = await connection.query(query2, audits);
      console.log(200, 'resAudit');

      return {resRestaurant, resAudit}; // You can return data here

    } catch(e) {
      console.log('err in requests', e); // you can also use try/catch block for each request
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Now It's inserting data to two tables but there is another issue  It doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I have updated my answer as well. =)